# PHP MySQL - Select all where expiry date = todays date + 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I am using PHPMyadmin and putting values in a database using PHP. I store the expiry date of products using a timestamp as follows,
FOR EXAMPLE:

```
2012-11-04
```

I want to select all where the expiry date is equal to todays date plus 8 days (such as the one above)

I also want to select all where expiry date is equal to todays date + 2 weeks in a seperate page if any one could help me out would be very grateful!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do that with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```

You can use `DATE_SUB` for dates in the past.

Answer (score 13):

> 1. Select all where the expiry date is equal to todays date plus 8 days

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
WHERE
    products.expiry_date >= DATE(now())
AND
    products.expiry_date <= DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```

> 2. Select all where the expiry date is equal to todays date plus 2 weeks

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
WHERE
    products.expiry_date >= DATE(now())
AND
    products.expiry_date <= DATE_ADD(DATE(now()), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

These docs will be helpful for you:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add