# PHP: Auto update a database field on a certain date, no scripts via cronjob

Tags: php, mysql, date

Not sure if it's even possible but is there a way to auto update a database field on a certain date?

I've just been given a system to work on and there is zero documentation on the processes and no comments within the code and more than 2000 files with thousands of lines of poorly written code. Btw it's a custom MVC system.

Now the current system automatically updates a database field 24 hours in advance before the date arrives. There are no cronjobs running. Could it be possible to auto update a field when a certain date occurs? Or is the code being triggered somehow? Can this be done via a PHP script?

Basically the system expires items 24 hours before their expiry date arrives.

Already been through the following material but no help so far:

[PHP and MYSQL date expiry near](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152523/php-and-mysql-date-expiry-near)

[get a time difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053799/get-a-time-difference-between-two-dates)

[PHP MySQL - Select all where expiry date = todays date + 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104639/php-mysql-select-all-where-expiry-date-todays-date-7-days)

http://www.interactivetools.com/forum/forum-posts.php?postNum=2215219

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/317765-how-to-set-expiration-date-in-php/

Comment: mysql has its own scheduler. or if the site is busy enough, it can simply check for "jobs to do" every time a hit comes in on the site.

Comment: I thought it might be the scheduler but it's disabled. So that's out of the question.

Comment: The tool for the job **is** what @MarcB mentioned. If you can't use it, then change your host or whoever it is that manages MySQL for you and use the one that will let you utilise event scheduler. It's really as simple as that.

Comment: Looks like you haven't read carefully. Even though the scheduler is disabled, the system still manages to change the value of the field. So it's not the scheduler that's making the changes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can draw attention at one more feature MySql - "Using the Event Scheduler"
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: I thought it might be the scheduler but it's disabled. So that's out of the question.